# Is it possible separate variables in equation?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I am trying to solve and integrate differential equation, but I am not sure am I on the right way, my original equation is:
$$ dz=-(r-z(r-1))^4d(p_0p_1)-8(r-z(r-1))^3 dp_0$$ where $r=const$.
If I use replacement $t=r-z(r-1)$, I got $dz=-\dfrac{dt}{r-1}$, and according to that:
$$ -\dfrac{dt}{r-1}=-t^4d(p_0p_1)-8t^3dp_0 $$
I don`t know how to integrate this equation, how to put everything with term $t$ on one side of equation, how to separate them? Or how to do that on other way?

Comment: You can't separate variables in this equation. Especially since there's $3$ of them

Comment: But how to solve it?

Comment: That depends. What is the original problem where this equation appeared and what kind of solution do you need?

Comment: You can write your second equation, for example, like this: $$(t p_1+8) \frac{d p_0}{dt}+tp_0 \frac{d p_1}{dt}-\frac{1}{(r-1)t^3}=0$$ Note that you have two unknown functions here, but only one equation. You can't find both functions without additional information.